# Why do I have to use assign() instead of eval(parse(text=())) in R

Tags: r, loops, assign

The problem arises when I want to use a loop to assign new values to several data frames.

I know the correct way is

```
for (df.name in c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')) {
  assign(df, new.value)
}
```

My question is, why can't I do this

```
for (df.name in c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')) {
  eval(parse(text=df.name)) <- new.value
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use eval/parse:

```
eval(parse(text= paste(df.name, "<- new.value")))
```

The error that you were getting,

> target of assignment expands to non-language object

is because `eval(parse(text=df.name))` returns the variable `df1`, which isn't an R expression to be evaluated.

---

Please remember that eval/parse is dark, dangerous, magic that leads to unmaintainable zombie code.  If you can find a different way to write your code, choose that instead.

---

As mentioned in the comments, if you have several data frames with similar properties, it is often easier to work with them as a list.

```
df_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
```

Then you can use `lapply` to manipulate each data frame in a loop, or combine them into a single data frame using `rbind` or `dplyr::bind_rows`.

Comment: Ah! So eval(parse(text=()) will returns something that will get evaluated right away. I mistakenly thought that it is a way to turn string into object name within code.

Comment: +1 For the last sentence. I'm ambivalent if it is right to show how to do this to people who obviously don't know that there is a better/saver/easier way (e.g., using lists). It might just support bad habits.

Comment: For example (per @Roland 's comment), create `bigdf<-list(df1=df1,df2=df2,...` and it'll be easy to operate on elements of that list.

Comment: Thanks! This is also useful for assigning values to a new column on a data frame, while both or one of data frame name and variable name could be parameters.